# Recover damaged grub loader on Scientific Linux 6.3

Tags: grub, scientific-linux

[image: Screenshot of a Grub command line]

So... there is a notebook far away from me, and I can only sit in front of it in about a month. So I'm searching for a solution - "remotely".

Scientific Linux 6.3 is installed on it, and it worked perfectly. One day the people that use it sent me this picture.

**Q**: How can I fix the GRUB menu? So that they can use the notebook again?

P.S.: There was an auto-update configured on that machine besides the base install, here is how I implemented it:

```
yum remove -y PackageKit* yum-autoupdate yum-updateonboot; read; vi /etc/yum-update
```

---

```
cat yum-update
#!/bin/bash
# run an update in at least every 172800 seconds [in at least every 48h]

# wait for random time:  0-2700 sec [0-45min]
/bin/sleep $[ ($RANDOM % 2701 ) ]

if [ `stat --format=%Y $0` -le $(( `date +%s` - 172800 )) ]; then 
    # sync time - http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/hu
        /usr/sbin/ntpdate time.kfki.hu 0.hu.pool.ntp.org; /sbin/hwclock --systohc

    # do updates
        /usr/bin/yum -q -y update
        /usr/bin/yum clean all

    # update last modification time + create log entry
        /bin/touch $0
        /bin/echo "/etc/yum-update OK" | /usr/bin/logger
fi
```

---

```
chmod +x /etc/yum-update; crontab -e
52 * * * * bash /etc/yum-update
```

P.P.S.: They tried to press up/down when the machine booted (hoping to select another kernel) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've somehow corrupted or lost your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` or `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. The good news is that your kernel is probably still there, and probably still bootable (unless your entire filesystem has corrupted or something).

The GRUB shell is actually [pretty functional](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands.html#Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands). You can use it to diagnose and fix your broken configuration, but that's quite hard if you're not physically present. A better option is probably to get to a working kernel, then log in remotely (e.g. via ssh) to check things out.

Assuming you can get your colleagues to run some commands, you should be able to boot them into Linux. They can use tab complete to find the names of the relevant files.

1. **Load the kernel:**

   `grub> kernel  /vmlin<TAB>`
2. **Load the initrd:**

   `grub> initrd /initrd-<TAB>`

   Obviously, make sure the versions of the two selected files match.
3. **Boot:**

   `grub> boot`

See [this guide](http://server-support.co/blog/sysadmin/linux-booted-into-grub-shell-now-what/) for screenshots and more details, including some tips for diagnosing your menu problems.

Once you've got them up and running, you'll need to figure out what went wrong. I won't go into that here though, since there are lots of things that *might* have happened, and corresponding ways to fix the situation. You'll have to do some detective work to find out.

**For example:** Someone might have accidently deleted a file in `/boot`. Your `menu.cfg` may have become corrupted. A kernel update may have screwed up the menu during a routine run of `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig`. Permissions may have been changed incorrectly. Your `menu.cfg` may have been changed to point at the wrong `root` device. Your disk may be in trouble (in which case you have bigger problems). And so on.

Comment: Thanks! we tried :D the kernel line was OK. the initrd line was only possible with an ititramfs-Xversionetc.X (because there weren't any initrd, so we tried initramfs), then we tried "boot". OK! but all that we get is some messages, then a blinking cursor (and when they are seeing the blinking cursor they can't type anything)...I'm thinking that I will burn them an ubuntu desktop live CD, then they boot the livecd on the notebook, then I can reach the machine via network/ssh... to see the filesystem... but I don't know what to do then.. :\ AFAIK it will be a reinstall locally..

Comment: @gasko peter - Yes, `initramfs` is a replacement for `initrd`, and is run in the same way. Sorry it didn't work. Did you also try running an older kernel + associated initramfs file (it could be that just the latest `initramfs` is corrupted)?

Comment: we will try with an older kernel tomorrow :) thanks for the info

Comment: ehh, today we tried with all the kernel... no luck.. the same problem